Won Fin Anymore? (Won't Fit Anymore?)
Why does she says it like "Won Fin Anymore?" in the below movie ? It's impossible to understand it without subtitles.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdQShdZaih8&t=247s
I have never heard of such a saying. Is it an accent that belongs to a place in America?

I think it's "won't fit any more?" because she asks if he's too fat and he comments about putting it on. Margot Robbie is Australian but I think that's a Brooklyn accent she's affecting, New York anyway. (Not sure there's an actual question about the English language here.)

It's not a Brooklyn accent. It is just a completely nasalized utterance where the t in won't and fit are dropped. Saying wown (like sown) for won't is common in fast AmE speech. She does not push her sound far forward in the mouth which is what is needed in a Brooklyn accent. Believe me, I lived with those accents for years. And fin for fit is not that common. I think she just goofed and the director just went with it.

I agree with @Lambie that won’t is often pronounced something like wown in fluent American English. And I ‘d add that the “n’t” often becomes not just an n sound, but nearly an ng (as in sing) followed by a glottal stop (as the only remnant of the final t).  An example utterance where this would likely be heard is It won’t work, where the t is never pronounced as a t.

The /t/ in won't and fit is being replaced by a glottal stop. This is called "t-glottalization" and it is common in many British, American and Australian dialects. If you haven't heard anything like it, you probably haven't been listening closely.

@PeterShor I'm not sure the girl in the video say fin at all...it's more like the n sound from anymore is being squished together with fit: It wown fininnymore. There's no clear separation between those two words. In that sense, the /t/ disappears but there is not an added n. Just two squished together words.

@PeterShor Indeed so; her [wõʔˈfɪʔˌɛnɨˈmowɚ] pronunciation doesn’t seem all that unusual to me—let alone for a person with chewing gum in her mouth. :) I do think t-glottalization is the answer here, and that it's far more common in the real world than ESL teachers may always credit.

She's (heavily) chewing. By the way, this seems to be one of the crappiest films I have ever been exposed to.

Subtitles shouldn't be taken as authoritative. They're often written by people with no more familiarity with the media than the average viewer. Subtitlers don't necessarily have access to film scripts or anything other than their own intuition as a subtitler, and generally work for a company that is subcontracted, with the individual subtitler and production company having no direct relationship.

I listened very closely to the young lady. I think this is t-deletion. The first (won't) is t-glottalization but the second is not.

I don't know if "identify this accent" questions are allowed or not, but it's definitely pointless when it's an Australian doing an exaggerated caricature. The fictional city of Gotham (where I guess the film is set) is allegedly located in New Jersey, but there's no attempt to be authentic. BTW, it would be nice if the OP identified the film and actors.

@James: I don't know whether you were casting doubt on these particular subitles or not, but I'm a native speaker of American English and I think that she is clearly saying "won't fit anymore".

[wõʔˈfɪʔˌɛnɨˈmowɚ] is just t-glottalization
As was pointed out in comments, this is nothing more than a routine instance of t-glottalization, a common phonological effect.
Her [wõʔˈfɪʔˌɛnɨˈmowɚ] pronunciation doesn’t seem all that unusual to me—let alone for a person with chewing gum in her mouth. :)
Such t-glottalization is more common in the real world than ESL teachers may always credit.

I'm pretty sure that the second /t/ is flapped, not glottalized.

@alphabet Oh, maybe — but it doesn’t sound all that voiced so I’m not sure what symbol to use if it stops the glottis; maybe [ɾ̥] or [t̚], and that following an [ɪ̃] if it’s nasalized a bit the way it is in inch or finch.  // Got any theories as to why the asker found it impossible to understand without subtitles yet every native speaker immediately apprehends precisely which words were said without a hitch?

I actually had trouble understanding it also; without the following line for context I'd have been confused myself.

It may be relevant that the actress (Margot Robbie) is Australian, but imitating an American accent. AusE also includes /t/-flapping, and you can hear it from Robbie in interviews where she's speaking her native accent. But I'm not sure it's phonetically identical to the American version. If you listen to this interview, her pronunciation of the /t/ in fanatic at 0:57 also sounds flapped but not quite fully voiced.

(Of course, one must distinguish between ordinary voicelessness, where the vocal folds are spread apart, and a glottal stop, where they're shut closed. Certainly I don't hear the effects of the latter in her pronunciation of fit.)

The second is t-deletion. She doesn't say /t/ at all. For me, it's fin,innymore. All run together in her connected speech. No word boundary.

Margo Robbie is attempting to emulate a Brooklyn accent. See this example, this example for some similar speech patterns.

Someone with that sort of accent wouldn't have pronounced the /r/ in anymore, but she does.

@alphabet - Margo Robbie who is... Australian

She's slurring together the words "fit" and "anymore", resulting in something that sounds like "finanymore". It's kind of a Brooklyn or New Joisey accent, but not complete because she has a rhotic /r/ at the end of "more".

Yep, only fin-innymore, not anymore. Something like: |fɪn ˈnɪni mɔː| Please note: I am not a phonetician, etc. so my level of detail is not great.

Are people saying that it's a Brooklyn accent because Harley Quinn is supposedly from Gotham City, or because it actually sounds like one? She's certainly tryiing to speak with an American accent rather than an Australian one, but I really don't see anything specifically Brooklynish about her don' fi' anymore.

It's some kind of stereotypical accent from the New York City area, maybe a mixture.
